# Count and Avg in query to determine if result is greater than x

Tags: sql

I have taken the chance to learn sql. I have a basic table named `book`. I have been presented with the scenario: display the book category, and the number of 
books in each book category for books with an average price greater than 15 
dollars. My query below is not working. How can i count each book `type` and get the average price to see if it greater than 15?

Query

```
SELECT type FROM books WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT type) * SUM(price) > 15;
```

Table Schema

```
Select * From Book;

BOOK TITLE                                    PUB TYP      PRICE P
---- ---------------------------------------- --- --- ---------- -
0180 A Deepness in the Sky                    TB  SFI       7.19 Y
0189 Magic Terror                             FA  HOR       7.99 Y
0200 The Stranger                             VB  FIC          8 Y
0378 Venice                                   SS  ART       24.5 N
079X Second Wind                              PU  MYS      24.95 N
0808 The Edge                                 JP  MYS       6.99 Y
1351 Dreamcatcher: A Novel                    SC  HOR       19.6 N
1382 Treasure Chests                          TA  ART      24.46 N
138X Beloved                                  PL  FIC      12.95 Y
2226 Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban ST  SFI      13.96 N
2281 Van Gogh and Gauguin                     WP  ART         21 N
2766 Of Mice and Men                          PE  FIC       6.95 Y
2908 Electric Light                           FS  POE         14 N
3350 Group: Six People in Search of a Life    BP  PSY       10.4 Y
3743 Nine Stories                             LB  FIC       5.99 Y
3906 The Soul of a New Machine                BY  SCI      11.16 Y
5163 Travels with Charley                     PE  TRA       7.95 Y
5790 Catch-22                                 SC  FIC         12 Y
6128 Jazz                                     PL  FIC      12.95 Y
6328 Band of Brothers                         TO  HIS        9.6 Y
669X A Guide to SQL                           CT  CMP      37.95 Y
6908 Franny and Zooey                         LB  FIC       5.99 Y
7405 East of Eden                             PE  FIC      12.95 Y
7443 Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire      ST  SFI      18.16 N
7559 The Fall                                 VB  FIC          8 Y
8092 Godel, Escher, Bach                      BA  PHI         14 Y
8720 When Rabbit Howls                        JP  PSY       6.29 Y
9611 Black House                              RH  HOR      18.81 N
9627 Song of Solomon                          PL  FIC         14 Y
9701 The Grapes of Wrath                      PE  FIC         13 Y
9882 Slay Ride                                JP  MYS       6.99 Y
9883 The Catcher in the Rye                   LB  FIC       5.99 Y
9931 To Kill a Mockingbird                    HC  FIC         18 N
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to have the aggregations in the filter then you should `GROUP BY` and then use the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT type FROM books 
GROUP BY type
HAVING COUNT(*) * SUM(price) > 15;
```